# Plot predictions with simultaneous interval from gam over the range of the smoothed variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, prediction, gam, mgcv

I am running a gam model using the `mgcv` package with one smoothing spline and two factor variables as additional controls. I want to show a plot of predictions over the whole range of the independent smoothed variable (with simultaneous intervals):

```
library(mgcv)

mod <- gam(dv_value ~ age_grps + period.f + s(born_adult), data = dat, contrasts = list(age_grps = contr.sum, period.f = contr.sum))
```

I first calculate the predicted values over the whole range of the `born_adult` variable with simultaneous interval, which seems to work quite well:

```
rmvn <- function(n, mu, sig) { 
  L <- mroot(sig)
  m <- ncol(L)
  t(mu + L %*% matrix(rnorm(m*n), m, n))
}

Vb <- vcov(mod)

pred <- predict(mod, se.fit = TRUE)

se.fit <- pred$se.fit

N <- 10000

BUdiff <- rmvn(N, mu = rep(0, nrow(Vb)), sig = Vb)

Cg <- predict(mod, type = "lpmatrix")
simDev <- Cg %*% t(BUdiff)

absDev <- abs(sweep(simDev, 1, se.fit, FUN = "/"))

masd <- apply(absDev, 2L, max)

crit <- quantile(masd, prob = 0.95, type = 8)

predData <- transform(cbind(data.frame(pred), dat),
                      uprP = fit + (crit * se.fit),
                      lwrP = fit - (crit * se.fit))
```

However, when trying to plot the results, I get a really weird plot:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = born_adult, ymin = lwrP, ymax = uprP), data = predData, alpha = 0.2, fill = "red")
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/uskj9oyq8ud3zx2/plot1.png?dl=0

But, when faceting by my control variables, I get proper predictions for the separate "slices" of my data:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = born_adult, ymin = lwrP, ymax = uprP), data = predData, alpha = 0.2, fill = "red") + 
  facet_wrap(vars(period.f, age_grps))
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yju68yl8kes8mp1/plot2.png?dl=0

I have also tried predicting on a new simulated data set using the same structure as my data, however, the problem remained the same. Is there any possibility to show the "average" predictions over the whole range of my independent smoothed variable, without having to facet by the control variables? I believe it could work by taking the mean predictions grouped by the values of the `born_adult` variable: `predData <- group_by(born_adult) %>% summarize(fit = mean(fit))` However, I have no idea on how to take the average of the simultaneous intervals for the single predictions.

Last but not least, here is a small subset of the data I am using:

```
dat <- structure(list(dv_value = c(0.8, 0.8, 0.4, 0.8, 1, 0.6, 0.6, 
1, 0.8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.4, 0.8, 0.8, 1, 0.4, 1, 0.6, 1, 0.8, 0.6, 
0, 0.6, 0.8, 0.8, 1, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1, 1, 1, 0.8, 1, 0.6, 1, 
0.6, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.6, 1, 1, 1, 0.6, 1, 1, 1, 0.8, 1, 0.6, 
0.6, 1, 1, 0.8, 0.6, 0.8, 0.6, 1, 0.8, 0.8, 0.6, 0.8, 0.8, 1, 
1, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1, 1, 0.6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.6, 0.8, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.6, 1, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 
1, 0.4, 0.8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.4, 1, 1, 0.6, 1, 1, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 
1, 1, 0.6, 1, 1, 0.6, 1, 0.8, 0.8, 1, 0.8, 1, 0.8, 1, 0.6, 0.8, 
1, 0.8, 0.6, 0.6, 1, 0.8, 0.6, 1, 0.6, 1, 0.6, 0.8, 1, 0.6, 1, 
0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.2, 1, 0.6, 1, 0.8, 0.8, 1, 0.6, 
1, 0.4, 1, 0.8, 0.8, 0.4, 1, 1, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1, 0.8, 0.6, 0.6, 
0.4, 0.2, 1, 0.8, 0.4, 1, 1, 0.8, 1, 0.8, 0.6, 1, 1, 1, 0.8, 
1, 0.6, 0.8, 0.8, 1, 1, 0.8, 1), age_grps = structure(c(1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), 
    period.f = structure(c(9L, 9L, 6L, 5L, 10L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 13L, 
    5L, 2L, 2L, 13L, 6L, 7L, 13L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 9L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 
    10L, 7L, 13L, 3L, 13L, 6L, 2L, 10L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 13L, 
    6L, 7L, 5L, 13L, 3L, 13L, 6L, 10L, 13L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 9L, 
    10L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 13L, 2L, 13L, 2L, 3L, 9L, 
    13L, 9L, 7L, 10L, 2L, 13L, 2L, 13L, 10L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 3L, 
    6L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 7L, 13L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 13L, 10L, 13L, 
    13L, 10L, 13L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 13L, 7L, 13L, 7L, 
    13L, 13L, 13L, 9L, 13L, 3L, 13L, 13L, 10L, 3L, 10L, 7L, 13L, 
    7L, 5L, 3L, 13L, 9L, 5L, 10L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
    9L, 6L, 10L, 5L, 13L, 13L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 
    9L, 2L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 2L, 13L, 10L, 13L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 
    6L, 2L, 5L, 13L, 5L, 3L, 9L, 7L, 13L, 7L, 3L, 9L, 7L, 9L, 
    3L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 6L, 
    6L, 10L, 2L, 10L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 13L, 3L, 13L, 3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("1991", 
    "1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", "1998", "2000", "2002", 
    "2005", "2008", "2014", "2018"), class = "factor"), born_adult = c(1994, 
    1953, 1937, 1944, 1996, 1977, 1944, 1953, 2001, 1976, 1963, 
    1950, 1978, 1984, 1938, 1969, 1928, 1977, 1943, 1945, 1951, 
    1968, 1959, 1971, 1978, 1998, 1951, 1976, 1951, 1987, 1950, 
    1969, 1955, 1946, 1981, 2008, 1968, 1975, 1957, 1942, 1950, 
    1978, 1993, 1986, 1974, 1982, 1960, 1948, 1953, 1943, 1980, 
    1963, 1943, 1944, 1958, 1953, 1937, 1971, 1971, 1983, 1954, 
    1984, 1979, 1952, 1984, 1946, 1959, 1949, 1979, 1953, 1947, 
    1980, 1979, 1996, 1973, 1964, 1952, 1955, 1948, 1980, 1961, 
    1994, 1991, 1949, 1979, 1947, 1941, 1955, 1962, 2004, 1974, 
    1993, 1976, 1994, 1994, 1974, 1976, 1990, 1946, 1947, 1961, 
    1941, 1991, 1986, 1983, 1983, 1988, 1953, 1990, 1965, 1961, 
    1971, 1979, 1977, 1956, 1948, 2015, 1973, 1988, 1935, 2004, 
    1983, 1948, 1993, 1976, 1960, 1959, 1980, 1968, 1968, 1970, 
    1940, 1949, 1964, 1941, 2005, 1959, 1954, 1969, 1988, 1959, 
    1989, 1971, 1975, 1989, 1980, 1953, 1955, 1959, 1972, 1986, 
    1988, 1974, 1981, 1998, 2001, 1959, 1970, 1960, 1944, 1986, 
    1984, 2000, 1946, 1978, 1930, 1952, 1956, 1979, 1982, 1969, 
    1980, 1961, 1973, 1951, 1979, 1982, 1970, 1974, 1998, 1944, 
    1941, 1950, 1948, 1978, 1999, 1955, 1930, 1961, 1942, 1962, 
    1980, 1983, 1974, 1992, 1949, 2003, 1949, 1949, 1976)), row.names = c(NA, 
-200L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just an issue due to the data being all mixed up because you are predicting for the observations.

This plot is based on yours, but I plot the fitted values, from `mgcv::predict.gam()` and you can see the issue immediately:

[image]

The red and blue lines are the upper and lower simultaneous intervals respectively, while the black line is the fitted value from `mgcv::predict.gam()`. As the latter hasn't been manipulated at all, I'm inclined to believe the intervals here.

This is what you get if you use the pointwise/across-the-function credible intervals:

[image]

which, apart from being narrower, exhibit the same behaviour.

If you are just trying to get predictions and simultaneous intervals over the range of `born_adult` for each combination of the two factor variables, then you should create new data to predict at that repeats a sequence of `born_adult` values for all combinations of `age_grps` and `period.f`. Here is do that for 50 values of `born_adult` — the fitted smooth is basically linear so even 50 is overkill but the intervals are smoother with larger *n* — using `expand.grid()`:

```
pdat <- with(dat, expand.grid(
  born_adult = seq(min(born_adult), max(born_adult), length = 50),
  age_grps = unique(age_grps),
  period.f = unique(period.f)))
```

Then, repeating your code but adding `newdata = pdat` in to the simultaneous interval calculations we get them for our prediction data not the original data

```
Vb <- vcov(mod)
pred2 <- predict(mod, newdata = pdat, se.fit = TRUE)
N <- 10000
BUdiff <- rmvn(N, mu = rep(0, nrow(Vb)), sig = Vb)
Cg <- predict(mod, newdata = pdat, type = "lpmatrix")
simDev <- Cg %*% t(BUdiff)
absDev <- abs(sweep(simDev, 1, pred2$se.fit, FUN = "/"))
masd <- apply(absDev, 2L, max)
crit2 <- quantile(masd, prob = 0.95, type = 8)
```

Here I create the same as your `predData`, but I `cbind()` on `pdat` instead of the original data, and I add the pointwise intervals just as a check:

```
predData2 <- transform(cbind(data.frame(pred2), pdat),
                       uprP = fit + (crit2 * se.fit),
                       lwrP = fit - (crit2 * se.fit),
                       uprCI = fit + (2 * se.fit),
                       lwrCI = fit - (2 * se.fit))
```

which when plotted using

```
ggplot(predData2) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = born_adult, ymin = lwrP, ymax = uprP),
              alpha = 0.2, fill = "red") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = born_adult, ymin = lwrCI, ymax = uprCI),
              alpha = 0.2, fill = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(x = born_adult, y = fit)) +
  facet_wrap(vars(period.f, age_grps))
```

gives this:

[image]

If you only want it for the *observed* combinations of `age_grps` and `period.f` you'll need to create the prediction data somewhat differently, but the general idea still applies. (Or you could just do what I did and then delete all rows where the combination of `age_grps` and `period.f` is not one of the observed combinations.)

Comment: Dear Gavin, thanks for your suggestion, which works fine when facetting the predictions by all values of my covariates. However, when including more controls, I believe this approach would not be appropriate any longer. I'll try to find another solution in the last days which allows showing the predictions within one plot and will post it in a few minutes as an answer to this question. Could you check whether this work-around is reasonable with regard to GAM models and its underlying assumptions of uncertainty?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Gavin for providing a solution to the faceted prediction plots! However, in order to generate a plot on the predictions for the observed values, I believe there might be a work-around applying the methods proposed by King et al. 2001 in order to get the predictions over the range of the independent variable in one plot.

The underlying problem is that the predictions for the cohorts vary by their values on the other covariates, making the plot looking so wiggly. In order to solve the problem, we can assume that the overall prediction for a given cohort is unobservable, but can imputed from the predictions and their standard errors, which we get from the `mgcv::predict.gam` function. Using the methods explained on page 53 in the King et al. 2001 paper, we are able to calculate the overall predicted values with their respective standard error.

Getting the overall prediction for every cohort is pretty straightforward, by just taking the mean of the predictions for each cohort. The overall standard error is a bit more complicated. It requires applying the following two formulas:

[image]

and

[image]

In order to implement these calculations in R, we can simply use some `dplyr` functions:

```
predData <- transform(cbind(data.frame(pred)))
predBornAdult <- predData %>% 
group_by(born_adult) %>% 
mutate(m = n(),
       mean_fit = mean(fit),
       S_sq = (fit - mean_fit)^2/(m - 1)) %>%
replace_na(list(S_sq = 0)) %>% # For those cohorts, where we only have one prediction
summarize(fit = mean(fit),
          S_sq = mean(S_sq),
          se.fit2 = mean(se.fit^2) + S_sq,
          se.fit = sqrt(se.fit2)) %>% 
ungroup() %>% 
mutate(uprP = fit + crit * se.fit,
       lwrP = fit - crit * se.fit) %>% 
select(born_adult, fit, uprP, lwrP)
```

Now that we have overall predictions for every cohort, we are able to plot them. However, we have to be aware that the observed values for the cohort are only integers, making point estimates and error bars more appropriate than ribbons, which again would look wiggly due to the fact that we have calculated overall predictions for each cohort separately.

```
ggplot(predBornAdult, aes(x=born_adult, 
                     y=fit)) + 
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lwrP, ymax = uprP)) +
geom_point(size = 1)
```

[image]

Since we always want to easily identify trends for both the predictions and its uncertainty, we can now add `geom_smooth` to visualize potential underlying trends:

```
ggplot(predBornAdult, aes(x=born_adult, y=fit)) + 
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lwrP, ymax = uprP), alpha = 0.2) +
geom_point(alpha = 0.2, size = 1) + 
geom_smooth(aes(y = fit), se = F, alpha = 0.5) + 
geom_smooth(aes(y = lwrP), se = F, alpha = 0.5, linetype = "solid", size = 0.5) + 
geom_smooth(aes(y = uprP), se = F, alpha = 0.5, linetype = "solid", size = 0.5)
```

[image]